# How do you change a variable function argument in python

Tags: python

I am trying to do something like this

```
x = 'no'
y = 'no'
z = 'no'

def xyz(arg):
    global x,y,z
    if foo in bar:
        if arg == 'no':
            print('yay')
            arg = 'yes'
        else:
            print('not yay')
    else:
        print('not yay')
        arg = 'no'

while True:
   xyz(x)
   xyz(y)
   xyz(z)
```

but it does not seem to change "arg" to yes or no. Any way I could do that?

Comment: Python does not have pass-by-reference semantics, assignment to an argument does not change anything outside of the function.

Comment: @bereal Actually Python does do pass-by-reference, but since `arg` is being reassigned, and since `x, y, z` are strings i.e. immutable, it's irrelevant.

Comment: Once you do `arg = ...` you simply bind the name `arg` in that scope to a new value. It will not affect `arg`'s old value...

Comment: @wjandrea it's irrelevant whether they are immutable, if they are lists, the result will be the same. Passing by reference mean ability to access/assign values in the calling stack frame (`void f(int &c)` syntax in C++), which is not applicable to Python.

Comment: @bereal Oh OK, I misunderstood the terminology

Answer (score 1):

i think your issue is that you're not ***returning*** your `arg`

like this:

```
def xyz(arg):
    global x,y,z
    if foo in bar:
        if arg == 'no':
            print('yay')
            arg = 'yes'
        else:
            print('not yay')
    else:
        print('not yay')
        arg = 'no'
    return arg
```

but you have to have a variable to write to after you have called the funtion,

```
example = xyz(arg)
```

Comment: Get rid of `global x,y,z`. OP only used it because they misunderstood how it worked. What they were intending was basically `x, y, z = map(xyz, [x, y, z])`.

Answer (score 1):

`arg` refers to a string object, e.g. `'no'`. It cannot affect any other names that refer to the same string, e.g. `x`. It can't even change the value of the string object since strings are immutable.

What you should do is `return` from `xyz` and reassign `x` in the calling scope:

(Here I've also simplified the function logic and put the assignments onto one line to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) them out.)

```
x = y = z = 'no'

def xyz(arg):
    if foo in bar and arg == 'no':
        print('yay')
        return 'yes'
    else:
        print('not yay')
        return 'no'

while True:
   x, y, z = map(xyz, [x, y, z])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a working script. You should return the required value in the function and handling it on the caller side (when you call the function with the parameter).

The below script generates a random string and it returns "no" or "yes" based on if "a" is in the string (And prints your original "yay").

**Code:**

```
# Import modules for random string generation.
import random
import string

x = "no"
y = "no"
z = "no"


def generate_random_chars(number_of_chars):
    """
    Generating a random string.
    :param number_of_chars: Number of generated chars
    :return: The string with random chars.
    """
    return "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(number_of_chars)).lower()


def xyz(arg):
    # Global variables are not needed. These are not used inside the function.
    # global x, y, z
    # Define the return value.
    return_value = "no"
    random_chars = generate_random_chars(10)
    print("Random characters: {}".format(random_chars))
    if "a" in random_chars:
        print("'a' is in generated chars")
        if arg == "no":
            print("yay")
            return_value = "yes"
        else:
            print("not yay")
    else:
        print("'a' is NOT in generated chars")
        print("not yay")
        # The following line is not needed because the default value of return in "no"
        # arg = "no"
    return return_value


# Only test in a 10th for loop Not in infinite while loop
for _ in range(10):
    print("X - Input: '{}' Output: '{}'".format(x, xyz(x)))
    print("Y - Input: '{}' Output: '{}'".format(y, xyz(y)))
    print("Z - Input: '{}' Output: '{}'".format(z, xyz(z)))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
Random characters: nbqrezimym
'a' is NOT in generated chars
not yay
X - Input: 'no' Output: 'no'
Random characters: ldbymrkarr
'a' is in generated chars
yay
Y - Input: 'no' Output: 'yes'
Random characters: cwlglelcqt
'a' is NOT in generated chars
not yay
Z - Input: 'no' Output: 'no'
Random characters: irjanpwnvh
'a' is in generated chars
yay
X - Input: 'no' Output: 'yes'
Random characters: rlvszdglqu
'a' is NOT in generated chars
not yay
Y - Input: 'no' Output: 'no'
Random characters: dnmvsjciwg
'a' is NOT in generated chars
```